# User control wont create instance of datacontext in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have tried to figure out why a UserControl i have created cant have its DataContext set in xaml like

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

If i do it throws an xamlparse exception saying DataContext=null.

if i instead in the codebehind do

```
this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

there is no problem at all.

the MainView and MainViewModel are both dll projects.
The Main Window only contains MainView.
MainView and MainviewModel Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UmlEditor.view.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UmlEditor.view"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:UmlEditor.ViewModel;assembly=UmlEditor.ViewModel"

             >
<!--This dosent work-->
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
            <Button Command="{Binding HeyCommand}" Content="i work" Width="100" Height="50"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace UmlEditor.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public ICommand HeyCommand { get; private set; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            HeyCommand = new RelayCommand(hej);
        }

        private void hej()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i am the bomb");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing that you first show the XAML part where you set the DataContext and later show the UserControl's XAML without that part. How does the XAML of the UserControl actually look like?

Comment: ok added where the i would set  the datacontext in the user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally figured it out.

as both view and viewmodel are two seperate .dll and the app(window) a seperate project.

The app need reference to both .dll even though it only directly uses view